# SQL Server: table design for changing Identity records

Tags: sql-server, database-design, primary-key

I have a view which displays test data from multiple sources for a GPS spot.
The view displays the "GPS Point ID" and some geological test results associated with this GPS Point.

The GPS-POINT-ID is like this : XYZ-0XX-CCCCC

- `XYZ` : Area
- `00XX` : ID
- `CCCC`: Coordinates

The GPS point name changes over time, the first portion of point name(XYZ-0XX) is same and doesn't change, but the Coordinate part (CCCC) changes according to new GPS point location.

I wanted to design a table that will have the previously mentioned view as a datasource. I need to decide about the following:

- Primary key: if I used the full GPS-POINT-ID, I won't be able to keep track of the changes because it changes frequently over time. I can't keep track of the point. and I can't link it to it's historical records.
- If I use the fixed part of GPS-Point-ID (XYZ-00XX) as a computed column, I can't use it as a primary key, because the same point has many historical records that have the same (XYZ-00XX) part, this will violate the primary key duplicate constraint.
- If I create an identity column that will increase for each new record, how can I keep track of each point name change and get the latest test data as well as historical data for each point (XYZ-00XX).

Sample rows from the view are attached in a snapshot.

[image: Sample Query from against the view]

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a Primary Key comprised of two columns: Fixed part of GPS-Point-ID and Coordinate part?

Comment: I tried that, but for the same GPS-POINT-ID+Coordinate part there will be multiple tests, which will make the two columns a duplicate.

Comment: Add `Update-Date` to the key.

Comment: You mean I'll have a composite key of "GPS-POINTID","COORDINATE","UPDATE-DATE" ?

Comment: Yes. I would use a clustered key in exactly that order of fields.

Comment: I'd be gratefull if you mention how to query the table for a single unique record after I created the composite  primary key you indicated above. Will select Distinct work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using identity for primary key with no business value.  I would store the data in two columns one with the static data and another with the changing data.  Then you can have a computed column that puts them together as one field if that is necessary.  You can also add a date field so that you can follow the history.  The static data column being the identifier that ties the records together.

I am assuming you do not want to use auditing to track historical records for some reason.  That is the approach I would normally take.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database

EDIT:
Sample query works if only one update can happen on a given date.  If more than one update can occur then the row_number function can be used instead of group by.

```
 Select *
        From Table T1
        Join (Select Max(MatchDate) MatchDate, GpsStaticData 
                 From Table Group By GpsStaticData) T2 
             On T1.GpsStaticData = T2.GpsStaticData And T1.UpdateDate = T2.MatchDate
```

EDIT:
Using Row_Number()

```
 With cteGetLatest As
 (
 Select UpdateDate MatchDate, GpsStaticData,
        Row_Number() Over (Partition By GpsStaticData, Order By UpdateDate Desc) SortOrder
)

 Select *
    From Table T1
    Join (Select MMatchDate, GpsStaticData 
                From cteGetLatest Where SortOrder = 1) T2 
            On T1.GpsStaticData = T2.GpsStaticData And T1.UpdateDate = T2.MatchDate
```

You can add more fields after Order By UpdateDate in the row_number function to determine which record is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, according to your answer, how can I query latest  test result for "RF-0014" ? If I don't don't know exactly the latest "Coordinate Suffix" ?

Comment: I will add a sample query to my answer.

Comment: This is great, This will join each static point data with latest test date. it is 100% intact, but if I want to be proactive and go for a salable solution that will work if the same static-Field has two tests simultaneously ? I assume also that this will not any field as a PK ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean in your last sentence.  I will update query to use row_number to handle multiple updates on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

--To avoid artificial columns overhead costs a compound Primary Key can be used:

```
-- Simulate the Source View
CREATE TABLE ybSourceView (
    [GPS-POINT-ID] VARCHAR(20),
    [Status] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    UpdateDate [datetime2],
    Reason NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OpId VARCHAR(15)
);

-- Source View sample data
INSERT INTO ybSourceView ([GPS-POINT-ID], [Status], UpdateDate, Reason, OpId)
VALUES ('RF-0014-9876', 'Reachable'   , '2015-01-27 13:36', 'New Updated Coordinate'                 , 'AFERNANDO'),
       ('RF-0014-9876', 'Reachable'   , '2014-02-27 09:37', 'New Updated Coordinate'                 , 'AFERNANDO'),
       ('RF-0014-3465', 'Reachable'   , '2015-04-27 09:42', 'New Updated Coordinate'                 , 'HRONAULD' ),
       ('RF-0014-2432', 'Reachable'   , '2013-06-27 12:00', 'New Updated Coordinate'                 , 'AFERNANDO'),
       ('RF-0015-9876', 'OUT_OF_Range', '2014-04-14 12:00', 'Point Abandoned, getting new coordinate', 'AFERNANDO');

-- Historic Data Table
CREATE TABLE ybGPSPointHistory (
    Area VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    Coordinates VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    [GPS-POINT-ID] VARCHAR(20),
    [Status] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    UpdateDate [datetime2] NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSUTCDATETIME(),
    Reason NVARCHAR(MAX),
    OpId VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT ybGPSPointHistoryPK PRIMARY KEY (Area, ID, UpdateDate) --< Compound Primary Key
);
GO

-- Update Historic Data Table from the Source View
INSERT INTO ybGPSPointHistory (Area, ID, Coordinates, [GPS-POINT-ID], [Status], UpdateDate, Reason, OpId)
SELECT LEFT(Src.[GPS-POINT-ID], LEN(Src.[GPS-POINT-ID]) - 10), RIGHT(LEFT(Src.[GPS-POINT-ID], LEN(Src.[GPS-POINT-ID]) - 5), 4), RIGHT(Src.[GPS-POINT-ID], 4), Src.[GPS-POINT-ID], Src.[Status], Src.UpdateDate, Src.Reason, Src.OpId
FROM ybSourceView Src
LEFT JOIN ybGPSPointHistory Tgt ON Tgt.[GPS-POINT-ID] = Src.[GPS-POINT-ID] AND Tgt.UpdateDate = Src.UpdateDate
WHERE Tgt.[GPS-POINT-ID] Is NULL;
```

--Tests (check Actual Execution Plan to see PK use):

```
-- Full history
SELECT * FROM ybGPSPointHistory;

-- Up-to-date only
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY Area, ID ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC) As HistoricOrder
    FROM ybGPSPointHistory
) a
WHERE HistoricOrder = 1;

-- Latest record for a particular ID
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM ybGPSPointHistory a
WHERE [GPS-POINT-ID] = 'RF-0014-9876'
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC;

-- Latest record for a particular ID in details (more efficient)
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM ybGPSPointHistory a
WHERE Area = 'RF' AND ID = '0014' AND Coordinates = '9876'
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC;

-- Latest record for a particular point
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM ybGPSPointHistory a
WHERE Area = 'RF' AND ID = '0014'
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC;
```

--Clean-up:

```
DROP TABLE ybGPSPointHistory;
DROP TABLE ybSourceView;
```